# How do I disable the power off warning for android?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

This is NOT a programming question, just a user question.

When I hold down the power button to turn off my Samsung Galaxy S, I get a prompt to select power off, airplane mode, etc. Fine. I pick power off. THEN, I get a second prompt telling me "The device will power off" and I have to click "Allow". I just want the ability to turn off my phone quickly. Can I disable at least the second prompt? Or is there a way to just press one button and turn off my phone without all the nag screens?

Comment: Is the Android rooted? Which Android version are you using?

Comment: No, not rooted. I just accepted the latest update, don't have phone on me.

Comment: Without root chances are low. There are [a lot of solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=power-off+site%3Awww.appbrain.com) – but as far as I can see, all of them require root.